# How to use styled-components in both piral app-shell and pilet apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, piral

I am currently working on building a PoC Piral app using the UI framework that was developed in house.  This UI framework relies on the `styled-components` module, which causes issues when both my piral app-shell and pilet app start using those styled components.

When I don't explicitly include `styled-compnents` I get this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'styled-components'
    at requireModule (dependency.js:7)
    at dependency.js:32
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at define (universalModuleDefinition:3)
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (universalModuleDefinition:7)
    at universalModuleDefinition:12
```

When I do add `styled-components` as a dependency, I get this error message and the piral app-shell fails to render:

> It looks like there are several instances of 'styled-components'
> initialized in this application. This may cause dynamic styles to not
> render properly, errors during the rehydration process, a missing
> theme prop, and makes your application bigger without good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://docs.piral.io/guidelines/tutorials/15-share-dependencies)

I had to list those dependencies in the piral app-shell's `package.json` file like so:

```
"pilets": {
    "externals": [
      "styled-components",
      "<internal ui framework>"
    ]
  }
```

After I did that, all the issues were resolved.